# Trying to add days using timedelta to several dates

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to add 2 days to the dates within the "due dates" column and then compare the adjusted due dates (the + 2 days) are overdue or on time based on the date signed. I keep running into errors when trying to add the 2 days due to not being able to add this to the timedelta class. The excel file that the code is pulling data is attached as well as the code. The current error I'm running into is:

> ValueError: time data '0   2022-08-19\n1   2022-08-15\n2   2022-08-01' does not match format '%Y:%M:%d'

I tried removing the header row which I believe the "0" is coming from but then that gives me an issue later on since I'm reading data from these named header columns. Please advise.

```
path_file = "/Users/cherease/Documents/Excel/python training test 2.xlsx"
xl = pd.ExcelFile(path_file)

read = xl.parse("Sheet1")
name_col = read['name']
days_to_comp = read['days to complete']
due_date = read['due date']
formatted_due_date = due_date.to_string()  
date_sign = read['date signed']

print('Due dates are:', due_date)
print('Date it was signed is:', date_sign)
adjusted_due_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(formatted_due_date, "%Y:%M:%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
print(adjusted_due_date.strftime("%Y:%M:%d"))
```

**Python code:**

[image: python code]

**Excel screenshot:**

[image: excel screenshot]

Comment: You need to show the error message you're getting. There is really no way to respond to your question without that, sorry.

Comment: its in his screenshot, I know direct code is better but its something

Comment: Post the full error traceback output in your post as text, please. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

seems like its throwing an error cause you have all your dates in 1 string with break characters in between, try splitting it into a list with regex first?

```
due_date_list = re.findall("\d[4]-\d[2]-d[2]", formatted_due_date)

for n,date in due_date_list:
    due_date_list[n] = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%M-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
```